# Yii2 datatables format datetime adds one hour

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Datatable in my Yii2 project, its has a column called streamtime, in the database the format for the streamtime is Y-M-d H:i:s and i am trying to convert it to d-M-Y H:i, but when i do this one hour gets added to the datetime.

```
<?= DataTables::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'label'=> 'Stream time',
                        'attribute'=>'datetime',
                        'format' => ['datetime', 'd-M-Y H:i'],
                    ],

                    'streamer.name',

                    'game',
                    'description',
                    // 'created_at',
                    // 'updated_at',

                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

[image: This is what showes up]
[image: This is the database time]

Comment: Please check you have correctly set your time zone `date_default_timezone_set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check you have correctly set your time zone `date_default_timezone_set`

Answer (score 1):

At this moment i solved it like this, it works but it's not the way it should be.

```
 <?= DataTables::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'value' => function ($data) {
                                return date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($data->datetime));
                                },
                        'label'=> 'Stream time',
                        'attribute'=>'datetime',
                        //'format' => ['datetime', 'd-M-Y H:i'],
                    ],

                    'streamer.name',

                    'game',
                    'description',
                    // 'created_at',
                    // 'updated_at',

                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use php

```
 'format' => ['datetime', 'php:d-M-Y H:i'],
```